# How to apply a JS function to several HTML elements using "this" keyword?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm a newbie on JS and I don't understand yet how to use "this" keyword.

Here is a simple html, and I want, for example, the `div` and the `p` elements to get a green border onmouseover with a JS function using `this` keyword or something else to make the function work on both or maybe any html element.

```
<div id="firstDiv" onmouseover="greenBorder()">
   <h1>I'm Bruce</h1>
</div>

<p id="firstP" onmouseover="greenBorder()"> I'm Batman </p>
```

And I know it's not correct but my JS code would be like :

```
function greenBorder(){
  this.style.border="1px solid green";
```

Thank you

Comment: Pass in the element.  `onmouseover="greenBorder(this)"`, and change your method to use it `function greenBorder(element) { ... }`

Comment: @Taplar Thanks for your comment. 
Ok for the HTML part but I don't get the JS part. _change your method_ I don't know what a method is but it's ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is set upon the invocation of a function. In this case your inline code is called like a function with `this` set to the element, but when you call `greenBorder`, its `this` is unset.

(If you were calling a property of an object, e.g. `myObject.myMethod()`, then the `this` would be set to the object `myObject` instead. Otherwise, it is `window` or, if your JavaScript code runs in strict mode, `undefined`.)

---

You can either explicitely set its `this`, using the [`.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) method:

```html
<p id="firstP" onmouseover="greenBorder.call(this)"> I'm Batman </p>
```

... this way, the code you posted will work as-is:

```js
function greenBorder () {
  this.style.border = "1px solid green"
}
```

---

Or, you can pass in the element as an argument:

```html
<p id="firstP" onmouseover="greenBorder(this)"> I'm Batman </p>
```

In the latter case you'd have to change your function to use the argument instead of `this`:

```js
function greenBorder (element) {
  element.style.border = "1px solid green"
}
```